# Using custom views from AppKit and UIKit in a SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui, multiplatform, uiviewrepresentable, nsviewrepresentable

I have a multiplatform SwiftUI app which uses a custom view that is platform-specific in that it derives from NSView on macOS and UIView on iOS. These are legacy classes written in Objective-C & I'd like to use them in my SwiftUI app.

The `ContentView` presented by the app looks like,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            CustomViewWrapper()
                .border(.yellow)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This wrapper `CustomViewWrapper` is platform-specific:

```
#if os(iOS)
struct CustomViewWrapper : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        CustomView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // TODO
    }
}
#else
struct CustomViewWrapper : NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        CustomView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        // TODO
    }
}
#endif
```

The custom view is in its Objective-C file `CustomView.h`,

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 0

#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
@interface CustomView : NSView
@end

#else

#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomView : UIView
@end

#endif
```

with its implementation in the corresponding `CustomView.m` file. This header is exposed to the Swift code via a bridging header. The problem is that the macro `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 0` always resolves to true and the code goes down the AppKit root on iOS too. The compiler throws an error about the unavailability of AppKit on iOS. On macOS, it compiles fine.

**Question:** what **macro can I use to separate code destined for macOS and iOS in my Objective-C files** when I'm in a single, multiplatform SwiftUI target? Or do I have to create two separate targets, one for macOS and one for iOS, and include files with AppKit views in the macOS target and files with UIKit views in the iOS target?

**Note that** if I replace my `CustomView()` above in `NSViewRepresentable` and `UIViewRepresentable` wrappers with simple `NSView()` and `UIView()` respectively,

```
    ...
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        UIView()
    }
    ...
```

and

```
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        NSView()
    }
```

it all works fine and the the views render on both macOS and iOS without any problems. This can be seen in the attached screenshots where the border is being provided by `.border()` in SwiftUI.

[image]

[image]